# Django modelform with extra field, permissions per object as manytomanyfield - am I doing it right?

Tags: python, django, permissions, many-to-many

Not sure if I should split it into separate posts, I'd have to basically copy paste the whole code with each question. I hope this is fine.

1. I have channels in my app. Each user can have different access level to each channel. I need to be able to query entries from every channel user can read. I've implemented it as ManyToManyField, is there a better solution?
2. In my permission model I have `ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)` and `unique_together = ("channel", "user")`. I use permission object with null user field to store default access level for not specified users. Will this get me into trouble? (null!=null on database level)
3. I want to set default access level in ChannelCreateForm so I've added extra field to it and overriden the form_valid method of the related view. Is there a more proper way to do this?
4. I'm kinda improvising here. Please point out any uglyness you find in my code. Here it is:

   ```
   class Channel(models.Model):    
       name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
       title = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
       description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)    
       owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
       permission = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ChannelPermission', related_name="permission")            


   class ChannelPermission(models.Model):
       PERM_CHOICES = (
               (0, 'none'),
               (1, 'read'),
               (2, 'post'),                                
               (3, 'edit'),
               (4, 'lock'),
               (5, 'manage'),
           )
       channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel)
       user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
       access = models.IntegerField( choices=PERM_CHOICES, default=0) 

       class Meta:
           unique_together = ("channel", "user")


   class ChannelCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
       access = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Default access', 
                                  choices = (
                                      (0, 'none'),
                                      (1, 'read'),
                                      (2, 'post'),                                
                                      (3, 'edit'),                                  
                                  ) 
       )

       class Meta:
           model = Channel
           fields = ['name', 'title', 'access', 'description']


   class ChannelCreate(CreateView):
       form_class = ChannelCreateForm
       template_name = 'index_form.html' 

       def form_valid(self, form):
           obj = form.save(commit=False)
           obj.owner = self.request.user
           obj.save()
           perm = ChannelPermission(user=None, channel=obj, access=form.cleaned_data['access'])
           perm.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('some_name'))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, I'd do this the same way.
2. I'd probably change 0, 1, 2 etc keys to short string just to make sure 0 would **never** makes any troubles. Also, it is good idea to have meaningful records in database rather then 0, 1, 2, etc. `default='none'` would look better then. Other then that it sounds fine.
3. Probably the better solution is to not make it in a view. I would do creation of `ChannelPermission` in `save` method of the `Channel` model. Also, probably the good idea is to move logic of default `ChannelPermission` creation into model manager.
4. how about that

   ```
   class Channel(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
       title = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
       description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
       owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
       permission = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ChannelPermission', related_name="permission")


   class ChannelPermission(models.Model):
       PERM_CHOICES = (
               ('none', 'None'),
               ('read', 'Read Only'),
               ('post', 'Post'),
               ('edit', 'Edit'),
               ('lock', 'Lock'),
               ('manage', 'Manage'),
           )
       channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel)
       user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
       access = models.IntegerField(choices=PERM_CHOICES, default='none')

       class Meta:
           unique_together = ("channel", "user")


   class ChannelCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
       access = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Default access',
                                  choices = (
                                      ('none', 'None'),
                                      ('read', 'Read Only'),
                                      ('post', 'Post'),
                                      ('edit', 'Edit'),

                                  )
       )

       class Meta:
           model = Channel
           fields = ['name', 'title', 'access', 'description']

       def save(self, commit=True):
           instance = super(ChannelCreateForm, self).save(commit)
           perm = ChannelPermission(user=None, channel=self.instance, access=self.cleaned_data['access'])
           perm.save()
           return instance


   class ChannelCreate(CreateView):
       form_class = ChannelCreateForm
       template_name = 'index_form.html'

       def form_valid(self, form):
           self.object = form.save(commit=False)
           self.object.owner = self.request.user
           self.object.save()
           return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
   ```

Comment: 2. I was mostly worried about unique_together "not working" with null values. 3. You say model but your code says form. ;] Yes it makes more sense to put it in the form code. Thank you.

Comment: in this case you should probably remove null=True, blank=True from ChannelPermission for user and create another field in Channel model called default_permission